# How to detect a given word in sentence using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, lexical-analysis

I am trying to detect a given word, for example in the following text:

```
for i in range(40):
```

I can easily detect all identifiers but it detects `for` as identifier not as "for". I use `r'[for]'` as regex but it is not working.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of the re module?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary actually it is not working in my case

Comment: Show some code where you try `r'\bfor\b'`

Answer (score 1):

i think its this, dependes on what version you are using

```
for i in range[a, z]:
and what ever yo want here
```

Comment: I am using 
 r'[a-zA-Z_]+'  for Identifier detection and my all keywords are detected as identifier

Comment: did you figure it out yet?